# BindingUtils in FlashBuilder 4.7

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, binding, flash-builder

I used BindingUtils from Flex library in my pure AS3 projects many times. It was fine in FlashBuilder 3, 4, 4.5 and 4.6, but in 4.7 it doesn't work.

When I make

```
BindingUtils.bindProperty(foo1, "bar1", foo2, "bar2");
```

it changes foo1.bar1 only once at the beginning, but all changes in foo2.bar2 don't influence on foo1.bar1 property. So my project, which worked in 4.6 doesn't work in 4.7.

Why is it so? Anybody please help me.

Comment: In Flash Builder 4.7 an ActionScript only project uses the new "Falcon" Compiler instead of the Flex Compiler.    Perhaps that is somehow related.

Comment: While FB 4.6 and FB 4.7 come with the same Flex SDK 4.6.0 you should try a command line/ant build with the SDK from the FB 4.7 installation to ensure there are no other influencing factors.